# 29 or 30 days of Elul

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, elul

Does the month of Elul ***ALWAYS*** have 29 days, or can it also have 30 days?

Also, if there are only 29 days of Elul and Mosheh went up to Mount Sinai on the first of Elul, and then came down on the 10th of Tishrei, how was he there for 40 days, and when did the count start?

Comment: Our calendar always has 29 days but in the past it could be 30

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95161/has-elul-been-made-full-since-the-time-of-ezra?